# Connection timed out in simple_html_dom.php

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Error message:

PHP Warning: 
file_get_contents(https://search.rakuten.co.jp/search/mall/%E3%81%B5%E3%82%8B%E3%81%95%E3%81%A8%E7%B4%8D%E7%A8%8E/):
 failed to open stream: Connection timed out in /root/apps/kpi_tool_poc/simple_html_dom.php on line 76, referer: http://test-dash.local/kpi_tool_poc/new_trend_word.php

Comment: fixed formatting to make it a bit more readable, please do add more details and show what you already tried.

Comment: The error is actually pretty clear: while opening the remote resource, the (TCP) connection gave a time-out. Things to try are to see if you can reach the resource from another machine (using e.g. a browser) and from your target machine (using e.g. curl or wget on unix machines or whatever means a windows box might have)

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells that there is not finding the file you want to open. Try to create an if with file_get_contents and after that to process the file